# DataNitro autoformats dates

Tags: python, excel, datanitro

I am using DataNitro in my spreadsheet.   When I write the values to a cell.   It automatically guesses if format looks like a date.   This is obviously not always helpfull!

```
dt_str = "08/20/13"
Cell("A1").value = dt_str
# puts date type in that cell
```

I am not sure whether this behaviour is from Excel 2010 or from DataNitro side.   As I am writing this i am getting more convinced that this is an Excel issue.    Anybody with experience on this?

Done some more research and I almost conviced it is Excel Issue.   Solutions when Entering data directly is starting the cell with a '    This is obviously? not possible if I come in from python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an Excel issue, and putting a single quote at the beginning is correct. You can do that as long as you use double quotes to delimit the string:

```
Cell("A1").value = "'10/1/2013"
```

Comment: thanks.   I am using the .table method to write a list of lists to excel.    Any way of influencing the behavior there.   Mixture of text, floats and dates that I would prefer to keep in text.   Btw is there a way to set custom format (for date) from DataNitro?

Comment: You can use a nested list comprehension:

    new_table = [["'" + str(a) for a in b] for b in old_table]

There's no way to set custom formats for now, but you can use strftime to write dates as custom texts.